# Why Negative Marks at Forum's Oversight

Tags: discussion, support

Negative vote for this Question gives, bad impression of Forum.

[Check by Knight NxC3+ Move Implications](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/16366/check-by-horse-nxc3-move-implications)

None of forum's maintain this partiality Kind. I want to understand the Over All Governance of this Forum. And like to Progress in Positive Notion rather.

Comment: Maybe dilemma of I feel Governance got to something for this as STEP. I couldn't articulate well. Bothering. Hereby its Q&A is good raised the need concern. Thank You Folks!

Comment: Just to mention that I tend to up-vote your posts. We do take questions asking for game analysis at all levels of play.

Answer (score 6):

The tooltip on the downvote button says:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

[image]

- You have not shown any research effort (e.g. some analysis of your own).
- Your question is unclear; what do you mean by 'implications' of a certain move? Or do you just want us to analyze your game?
- Your question is not useful; by the time Nxc3 is played, you're completely lost already. It's not a common tactic pattern either. It may be useful to *you* (I suppose so; otherwise you wouldn't have asked the question) but is not useful *to future visitors of the site*, which is the main criteria for a post's value.

Comment: Good analysis. Maybe showcased well. Do you have any more good answers further.